# How do I add a background from css when I receive an error message

Tags: css, background

I am trying to add a background that is saved under file path C:/Users/josef/Desktop/Landing Page/header.jpg.  I know the file path is correct as I have copied this from file explorer.  However, when I open developer tools I get the message

'GET file:///C:/Users/josef/Desktop/Landing%20Page/%3Clink%20href= net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND.'

The code I in my css is `background:url(C:/Users/josef/Desktop/Landing Page/header.jpg);`

I'm sure it pretty simple but an extra pair of eyes would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Give relative path also url value should be enclosed with `' '`

Answer (score 0):

Umm, just get the image somewhere close to your html file? You know people do like `assets/image.jpg` or something like that... I was getting that error too when I was trying to get the image from my desktop. So just try opening an assets folder into the folder which contains your index.html

Comment: Index, CSS, and the background photo are all in the same folder.

Comment: yeah but i mean keep them close to index.html and don't get it all they way down from C: folder

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but still no luck.